# Regex for validate string of int range

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I am trying to build regex that can validate number or range input. 
Allowed values are

- Any number between 1 and 1816
- A range consisting of 2 numbers separated by -. Each number must be between 1 and 1816. E.g. "1-1816", "3-100", "1815-1816"

Invalid values include

- "0"
- negative numbers (like "-13")
- numbers with leading zeros (like "01")
- numbers out of range 1-1816 (alone or as part of range)

Any regex will be fine JavaScript or C#.

So far I figured out just

```
(?<=\s|^)\d+(?=\s|$)
```

Comment: Use regex like `(\d{1,4})(-\d{1,4})?` to extract numbers from string. After this parse this numbers as int and check they ranges with normal `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your regex is that you are accepting all digits via `\d` and not limiting it to suit your accepted range.

Use this:

`^(?:181[0-6]|180\d|1[0-7]\d{2}|[1-9]|\d{2,3})(?:-(?:181[0-6]|180\d|1[0-7]\d{2}|[1-9]|\d{2,3}))?$`

This regex limits the numbers to be in the range 1-1816, while supporting either individual numbers or a range via a hyphen separator as specified.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5OwIxc/1)

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the trick:

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-7][0-9]{2}|180[0-9]|181[0-6])(-([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-7][0-9]{2}|180[0-9]|181[0-6]))?$
```

Basically it allows

- A number with leading 1 and 0 to 2 more digits
- A number with leading 1, followed by 0-7 and twice any number
- A number with leading 180 followed by one more number
- A number with leading 181 followed by one number 0-6
- This optionally once more repeated after -

But generally regexes are not good to work with numbers (and hard to update whne the number changes). If you have such option I'd rather just validate the number by much simpler regex, like

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,3}(-([1-9][0-9]{0,3}))?$
```

and than programmatically split it by - (if present) and parse the individual segments as integer and validate their numeric value against the range.

That would additionally allow you to check for invalid ranges like 100-1, 1800-1800 etc.

Comment: the groups don't have to be capturing!

Comment: Sure, it's just more readable with capturing groups ;-). Here's the non-capturing version:     ^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-7][0-9]{2}|180[0-9]|181[0-6])(?:-(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-7][0-9]{2}|180[0-9]|181[0-6]))?$

Comment: On the other hand the simple regex can leverage the capturing groups like this ^([1-9][0-9]{0,3})(?:-([1-9][0-9]{0,3}))?$ and than no splitting by - is needed, captured groups can be used to extract the one or two matched numbers

Comment: I like to think I have a fairly good idea what capturing groups do. But they aren't needed in this situation since all the OP wants is to match a few strings, and not capture any data.

Comment: Besides capturing, which is not so relevant here, the capturing groups also do grouping. There is difference if you write abc? and (abc)? (ab mandatory + c optional vs. entire string optional). Why I use capturing gropus instead of non-capturing groups - the capturing groups are just so much easier to write and read - capturing (abc); non-capturing (?:abc) and you don't have to care that they are capturing if you don't use the capture.

Comment: Easier to read and write, yes. What about performance? There's a reason we have non-capturing groups.